# Select the value of user-defined variables with rand() in mysql

Tags: mysql, random, local-variables

I have a select query like this:

```
SELECT @imageID := imageID AS imageID, likeCount, path, `name`, description 
    from VIEW_Select_Client_PopularImages 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; 
SELECT @imageID;
```

actually I want the `@imageID` to use it in another query. but my problem is that some times the `imageID` in first select query is different from `@imageID` in the second select query!

not sure, but `@imageID` in all my tests is the biggest number between all `imageIDs` column.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @imageID will be set to the last item read by the table. In most cases, it goes in order they were added so you probably get the ID for the last imageID in the table. Indexing can change that.

mysql actually sets @imageID once for every item in the table, then randomly sorts them and picks the first one. It must create a random number for each row.

If you want to do this, try:

```
set @imageID = (SELECT imageID from VIEW_Select_Client_PopularImages order by  rand() limit 1);
```

Then use a second query to get the other values for @imageID.